# How can I get a reference to the parent object when deserializing XML in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, parent-child

I can't seem to get this working, here is my (stripped down) code: -

```
[XmlRoot("report")]
public class Report
{
    [XmlArray("sections"), XmlArrayItem("section")]
    public List<Section> Sections;
}

public class Section
{
    public Report Report;
}
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your objects contain circular references which is not supported by the [XmlSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx) class. You could instead look at the [DataContractSerializer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractserializer.aspx) which [supports](http://www.jameskovacs.com/blog/GoingAroundInCirclesWithWCF.aspx) such scenarios.

Comment: this is also the preferred default mechanism for serialisation now in the absence of compelling reasons for the older mechanisms.

Comment: I'd post the finished code if I had more than 300 characters to play with, but suffice to say, using the DataContractSerializer worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure you know how you want those classes to serialize and deserialize. Write the XML you want as a result, and figure out how you want objects to become XML and vice versa. It's not a no-brainer.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution. It might not be as elegant as you'd expect:

```
public class Report
{
  //...


  void PostLoad()
  {
    foreach(Section s in Sections)
    {
      s.Report = this;
    }
  }

  public static Report Load(string filename)
  {
    // Load using an XmlSerializer
    Report report = ...;

    report.PostLoad();

    return report;
  }
}
```